"Go to Source" was missing from TeXstudio. Has anyone found the answer yet?
I recently came across the issue of "go to source" missing from the menu in the pdf viewer and it seemed to have to do with the SyncTex file. I saw a lot of answer that did not work. I finally found the solution which was to close any other opened tex files in the program. That solved the issue. My question is, in all these years of this issue have others found this solution?
